# How to get values from a form posted using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I was trying to submit a form using a javascript function,and below is my javascript function

```
   function submit_form(id_textarea,image_name_IN){
//var value_filled_textbox=document.getElementById(textarea_id_in).value;
var form=document.createElement("form_temp");//temporary dummy form
form.setAttribute("method","post");//its a post method
 form.setAttribute("action","comment.php"); // to which the page needs to be submitted

    var comment_value=document.getElementById(id_textarea).value; // gets the content of textarea
   // alert(comment_value);// just to make sure that you are getting the commeted text area content
     //create a hidden field for comments text
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "comment_content");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", comment_value);

           form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        //   create a hidden field for passing image name
        var hiddenField2 = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField2.setAttribute("name", "image_name" );
            hiddenField2.setAttribute("value",image_name_IN );

            form.appendChild(hiddenField2);

   document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
//alert(value_filled_textbox);
window.open("http://127.0.0.1/comment.php");
//document.getElementById('myform').submit();
}
```

while posting comment ,
**I was getting two comment.php window,one with a result and the other with two warnings saying that undefined values  "image_name" and "comment_content"**

Comment: use jQuery submit http://api.jquery.com/submit/ to submit form.

Comment: *What* isn't a function?

Comment: im getting that submit.form() is not a function

Comment: `submit.form()` is not shown anywhere here.

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe Don't, just don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form must be a `<form>` ... you used a non-existing HTML element `<form_temp>` which (of course) doesn't have a submit() method

```
var form=document.createElement("form");//temporary dummy form
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because form_temp is not a vaild form element. create a just a form element and it will get the submit function

```
var form=document.createElement("form");//temporary dummy form
```

Answer (score 0):

USE

var comment_value=document.getElementById('id_textarea').value;

instead of

var comment_value=document.getElementById(id_textarea).value;

Comment: if i use var comment_value=document.getElementById('id_textarea').value; then it shows a error that document.getElementById is null